# Formula for Average Customer Lifespan in excel for Customer Lifetime Value

Tags: excel, commerce

I am trying to calculate the Customer Lifetime Value. I have all the components except for the Average Customer Lifespan, which I am having trouble compiling into a formula.

My data in excel have all the historical purchases made by all customers. A purchase creates multiple rows for each item purchased in that order (not important here). Attached is an example of data that I have simplified.

Column B has the Customer name (unique for each customer), Column C has the date of the purchase/order and Column D has the Unit No.

What I need it for each individual customer to calculate the date difference between his first and last purchase (in this case the number of days). (The cell H2 and H3 just shows the steps in between for better understanding). The Cell H4 is then the average of the numbers in H2 and H3.

At the same time, I need this to be calculated only if the Unit No. in Column D matches "62". (Therefore the calculation is not done for customer "C".)

**I'd like have the whole formula in one cell, that would produce the result seen in cell H4. Can you please help me with that?**

Thank you

[screenshot of excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTry0.jpg)

I tried ChatGPT, which didn't produce the expected result.

Comment: out of curiosity, what did chatgpt answer?

Comment: Columns start at A and it does not include the Unit No. filter

=AVERAGE(IFERROR(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A:A<>"",MATCH(A:A,A:A,0)),IF(A:A<>"",MATCH(A:A,A:A,0)))>0,
    MAXIFS(B:B, A:A, INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,"<>"&""),B:B,0))),
    "") - MINIFS(B:B, A:A, INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MINIFS(B:B,A:A,"<>"&""),B:B,0))),
""))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no version constraints, as per your tags, the following formula, entered into a single cell, will produce the output:

```
=LET(
    c, UNIQUE(Purchase[Customer Name]),
    dys, IFERROR(
        BYROW(
            c,
            LAMBDA(arr,
                LET(
                    f, FILTER(
                        Purchase[Purchase Date],
                        (Purchase[Customer Name] = arr) * (Purchase[Unit No] = 62)
                    ),
                    MAX(f) - MIN(f)
                )
            )
        ),
        ""
    ),
    avg, AVERAGE(dys),
    tbl, VSTACK(
        {"Customer Name", "Customer Lifespan"},
        HSTACK(c, dys),
        HSTACK("Average Lifespan", avg)
    ),
    FILTER(tbl, CHOOSECOLS(tbl, 2) <> "")
)
```

***Output from your posted table***
[image]

***Edit: Individual formulas avoiding `BYROW` and `LAMBDA`***+

```
N3: =SORT(
    UNIQUE(
        FILTER(
            Purchase[Customer Name],
            Purchase[Unit No] = 62
        )
    )
)

O3: =MAXIFS(
    Purchase[Purchase Date],
    Purchase[Customer Name], N3,
    Purchase[Unit No], 62
) -
    MINIFS(
        Purchase[Purchase Date],
        Purchase[Customer Name], N3,
        Purchase[Unit No], 62
    )

O4: =MAXIFS(
    Purchase[Purchase Date],
    Purchase[Customer Name], N4,
    Purchase[Unit No], 62
) -
    MINIFS(
        Purchase[Purchase Date],
        Purchase[Customer Name], N4,
        Purchase[Unit No], 62
    )

O6: =AVERAGE(O3:O5)
```

***Results from Formulas***
[image]

Comment: a) The formula gives me an error. Could it be because I have a Mac?
b) I just need the formula for cell H4. (H2 and H3 was just to show the steps in between.

Comment: @Howard_Roark what is your version of Excel? In your tags you did not mention any limitation

Comment: @Howard_Roark and also, what is the error?

Comment: This is the Mac version I have: 16.79.2 (23112723). Should be the latest.
The error just says #VALUE!

Comment: @Howard_Roark I don't have a MAC but it should work on that since you have `365`. I would start by applying it to your posted data (which would have been best posted as a copyable text table and not a screenshot). Ensure the structured references in the formula return the expected ranges.

Comment: I have tried it on a 365 PC version and your formula works. However, it does not work on MAC (I have Excel for Mac 2021, not the 365 version) :(

Comment: @Howard_Roark No it will not work in 2021. If you must work on a Mac, a VBA solution might be the way to go. Or possibly multiple helper columns. Or maybe update your Mac version to 365.

Comment: do you think you would be able to provide me with a formula that would give me just the end result? So that would be just the total formula that I would input into the cell H4 to get the result in H4? With this, we might get around some of the limitations of the Excel for Mac 2021 version. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, seems that the 'BYROW' and 'LAMBDA' functions are not in the 2021 Mac version. Will have to figure out VBA then. Thank you

Comment: @Howard_Roark Posted some formulas that do not require `BYROW(...LAMBDA(...))` Not as flexible but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(d,B2:D14,
uCustomer,UNIQUE(FILTER(INDEX(d,,1),INDEX(d,,3)=62)),
uDelta,BYROW(uCustomer,LAMBDA(c,MAXIFS(INDEX(d,,2),INDEX(d,,1),c)-MINIFS(INDEX(d,,2),INDEX(d,,1),c))),
VSTACK(HSTACK(uCustomer,uDelta),HSTACK("average",AVERAGE(uDelta))))
```

It first retrieves the unique customers with UnitNo 62.

Then calculates per unique customer the delat

Finally all information is put together by `HSTACK` and `VSTACK`

[image]

Comment: a) The formula gives me an error. Could it be because I have a Mac?
b) I just need the formula for cell H4. (H2 and H3 was just to show the steps in between.

Comment: a) I suppose yes, this formula uses the "new" array formulas.